# Non locking calls via python console for PythonQt library

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, qt

My Qt application has a Qt gui (basically some buttons and an opengl context which draws data). I've also added scriptability exploiting PythonQt classes. The commands are evaluated from inside a PythonQtScriptingConsole.

I've explicitly created wrapper classes and factory methods to send C++ calls via the current python context through the console, but when running long tasks from inside the console, the gui freezes because (I think) the event loop is not processed. So a first solution would be to process the event loop with a timer, but this is both slow and  kinda stupid I think, so I don't like it. A

Has someone some hint? Is the Python Global Interpreter Lock a problem here?

Comment: I think you can solve this with `QThread` http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the GUI is freezing because the long call into Python is being executed via the UI thread.  To get around this, I was able to subclass QThread and issue commands into the Python module via a Command pattern.

Before you start making calls into multiple Python modules using the following classes, be sure to initialize thread support in Python by calling PyEval_InitThreads() as you'll see in my main() function.

Good luck!

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

        QApplication qapp(argc, argv);

        PyEval_InitThreads(); // IMPORTANT
        PythonQt::init(PythonQt::IgnoreSiteModule | PythonQt::RedirectStdOut);

        PythonQtObjectPtr module = PythonQt::self()->createUniqueModule();

        ThreadedPythonContext context(module);
        context.start();

        # issue some commands into the module
        context.issue("import sys");
        context.issue("sys.path.append('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages')");
        context.issue("import time");
        context.issue("last = time.localtime().tm_sec");

        // Release the global interpreter lock (if it has been created and thread support 
        // is enabled) and reset the thread state to NULL, returning the previous thread 
        // state (which is not NULL). If the lock has been created, the current thread must 
        // have acquired it. (This function is available even when thread support is 
        // disabled at compile time.)

        // give up control of the GIL
        PyThreadState *state = PyEval_SaveThread();

        return qapp.exec()
}
```

ThreadedPythonContext.h

```
#ifndef THREADEDPYTHONCONTEXT_H
#define THREADEDPYTHONCONTEXT_H

#include "PythonQt.h"

#include <QtCore/QMutexLocker>
#include <QtCore/QQueue>
#include <QtCore/QThread>
#include <QtCore/QWaitCondition>

class ThreadedPythonContext : public QThread 
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ThreadedPythonContext(const PythonQtObjectPtr &context) : 
        QThread(), 
        _context(context), 
        _running(true)
    {
    }

    ~ThreadedPythonContext() {
        _running = false;
        wait();
    }
    void issue(const QString &code) {
        _lock.lock();
        _commands.enqueue(code);
        _lock.unlock();

        _CommandQueued.wakeOne();
    }

    bool isCommandQueueEmpty() {
        QMutexLocker lock(&_lock);
        return _commands.isEmpty();
    }

protected:

    QString dequeue() {
        QMutexLocker lock(&_lock);
        QString cmd( _commands.dequeue() );

        return cmd.isEmpty() ? "\n" : cmd;
    }

    void run() {

        QMutex signal;
        PyGILState_STATE state;

        while(_running) {

            // wait to be signaled ... 
            signal.lock();
            _CommandQueued.wait(&signal,1);
            signal.unlock();

            if ( isCommandQueueEmpty() ) {
                continue;
            }

            while ( !isCommandQueueEmpty() ) {

                PythonQtObjectPtr p;
                PyObject* dict = NULL;

                state = PyGILState_Ensure();

                if (PyModule_Check(_context)) {
                    dict = PyModule_GetDict(_context);
                } else if (PyDict_Check(_context)) {
                    dict = _context;
                }

                if (dict) {
                    // this command blocks until the code has completed execution
                    emit python_busy(true);
                    p.setNewRef(PyRun_String(dequeue().toLatin1().data(), Py_single_input, dict, dict));
                    emit python_busy(false);
                }

                // error in the kernel
                if (!p) {
                    PythonQt::self()->handleError();
                }   
                PyGILState_Release(state);
            }
        }
    }

    PythonQtObjectPtr _context;

    QMutex _lock;
    QQueue<QString> _commands;

    QWaitCondition _CommandQueued;  
    bool _running;

signals:
    void python_busy(bool);
};

#endif //THREADEDPYTHONCONTEXT_H
```